# I get an argument out of range exception when i remove the last element of a list, even when I make the code ignore it with "if (i <= List.Count)"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to change a button prefab's color untill another button prefab is clicked on, but if I select the last element, then delete it, I get an Argument Out Of Range Exception.

I tried to fix it by checking if the `previousID` is not bigger than the `prefabList.Count`. But it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

the code:

```
public void SetColor(List<GameObject> prefabList, int ID)
{
    if (prefabList.Count != 0)
    {
        if (previousID != ID && prefabList.Count >= previousID)
        {
            Debug.Log("ID: " + ID + "previous ID: " + previousID);
            prefabList[previousID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
            previousID = ID;
        }
        else if (ID == previousID)
        {
            prefabList[ID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.yellow;
        }            
    }        
}
```

the rest of the code:

```
private void Update()
{
    JLList = MenuManager.GetComponent<AddJL>().JLList;

    CheckForChange();
    SetEditorJL.SetColor(prefabList, JLID);
}

private void GenerateOptions()
{
    foreach (Transform child in ScrollViewContent.transform)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
        prefabList.Clear();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < JLList.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject newJLOption = Instantiate(ButtonPrefab, PrefabParent.transform);
        int JLIndex = i;
        newJLOption.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => LoadJL(JLIndex));
        prefabList.Add(newJLOption);
    }
}

private void LoadJL(int JLIndex)
{
    JLID = JLIndex;
    SetEditorJL.SetColor(prefabList, JLID);
}

private void CheckForChange()
{
    int allJLOptions = ScrollViewContent.transform.childCount;
    if (allJLOptions != JLList.Count)
    {
        GenerateOptions();
    }
}
```

Edit based on answers:

```
public void SetUnderEditJudgeLineColor(List<GameObject> prefabList, int ID)
{
    if (prefabList.Count != 0)
    {
        if (previousID != ID && prefabList.Count > previousID)
        {
            Debug.Log("ID: " + ID + "previous ID: " + previousID);
            prefabList[previousID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
            previousID = ID;
        }
        else if (ID == previousID)
        {
            prefabList[ID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }        
}
```

Sadly, I still get the same error.

Edit 2:

```
    public void SetUnderEditJudgeLineColor(List<GameObject> prefabList, int ID)
{
    if (prefabList.Count != 0)
    {
        if (previousID != ID && prefabList.Count > previousID)
        {
            Debug.Log("ID: " + ID + "previous ID: " + previousID);
            prefabList[previousID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
            previousID = ID;
        }
        else if (ID == previousID && ID < prefabList.Count)
        {
            prefabList[ID].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }        
}
```

it doesn't give an argument out of range exception now, but neither ID or previousID gets their values updated anymore.

Comment: 1) Is this line in the update loop intentional: `SetEditorJL.SetColor(prefabList, JLID);`?  2) Where is `previousID` stored?  Is it `static` or on `SetEditorJL`?  3) When should something be white and when should it be yellow?

Comment: @Foggzie yes, it is intentional, othervise it wouldn't change instantly change color after deleting any of the `newJLOption`. `previousID` is stored as `int previousID` in `SetEditorJL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prefabList.Count >= previousID` should be `prefabList.Count > previousID`.  The last index is always `List.Count - 1` (because indexes start at 0) so, if the index and count are equal, you're checking past the end of the list.

**EDIT:**

Your `else if` statement isn't protecting from `prefabList.Count` so that'll also need a check against the size of the list:

`else if (ID == previousID && ID < prefabList.Count)`

Comment: I feel like an idiot for forgetting that. EDIT: Nevermind, still doesn't work, but I still feel like an idiot.

Comment: @Qroo This answer was a single bug that was in your code.  If there's a new one, you should add the modified code (as an addition to the question below the old code, don't erase the old code), and we can continue digging into the problem(s).

Comment: I put the edited code there. but I don't think it was that necessary when only one character is changed.

Comment: thanks, now it doesn't give an exception. but according to the debug log, both ID and previousID is frozen.

Comment: @Qroo I won't be able to help further without more context.  If this is happening in a loop or something, you'll need to post that as well.  I'm not sure what you mean by frozen.

Comment: @Foggize this is the rest of the code. but I don't think anything's wrong there. But I admit that it could've been written better.